# How to export Sqlite Database to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sqlite, database-migration

I want to export my sqlite database to sql server.
I used many tools present in web for eg. sqlite expert professional and razorsql to generate sql scripts from the sqlite database.

But i am not able to execute the generated sql script in the sql server.
The problem is uniqueidentifiers used in my sqlite database is not exported in correct format to sql script file which can be recognized by sql server and i am ending up with the following exception in sql server 
"Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier."

Can anyone provide me a better way of exporting sqlite databse into sql server with uniqueidentifiers recoginized by sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

The `SQLite` `.dump` command will output the entire contents of the database as an `ASCII text` file.

for more details

http://sqlite.org/cli.html

you can use DB Browser for SQLite [Here](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Comment: @sandeepbyagoni so what is the problem